# nginx location block only in conf file

Tags: php, nginx, configuration

I was able to put a location block inside the default.conf file and have it work as expected.  It passed the correct files from the correct directory over to the php-fpm server and display the expected results.

Now, I want to move that location block to its own .conf file for maintenance and ease of leaving the main/default .conf file alone.

However, this is not working as I had hoped or expected. When I do this, nginx restarts just fine, but when I try to browse, I get a 404 error.

This is the conf file for just the location:

```
    server {

    location /myapp/ {
        root   /opt/myapp/htdocs;
        index  index.php;
        location ~ \.php$ {
                #root           html;
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9071;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

As I stated, if I copy this exact code into the main default.conf file, then it works.  But in its own conf file, it doesnt.

In the end, I want to be able to have a different conf file for each location, where each location represents a different version of my app, running on different version of php-fpm (which are already configured on their own ports).

In Apache I was able to do this using Alias and  blocks, each in its own conf file.  I am trying to do something similar with nginx.

Comment: Are you sure you're including the file correctly from the main conf file? This might be a better question for [serverfault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: Its in the conf.d directory, next to the default.conf.  If this is better for serverfault, I can go there.

Comment: That is the configuration file for a server. Are you trying to separate out locations, but keep then within the same server name?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I am trying to do.  all these locations will be part of the same server, but I want them in their own separate conf files.